# How to unfold the $E= (|I⟩⟩⟨⟨I|+|X⟩⟩⟨⟨X|)^{⊗2}$ and aquire the following equation?

Tags: quantum-operation

The standard notation of $|X⟩⟩$ for
the $4^n$-dimensional vector representing $X$ in the space acted on by superoperators. $E= (|I⟩⟩⟨⟨I|+|X⟩⟩⟨⟨X|)^{⊗2}$.

From this definition, How comes
$E|I⟩⟩=(Tr(I) I + Tr(X ⊗ I) X ⊗ I+ Tr(I ⊗ X) I ⊗ X + Tr(X ⊗ X)X ⊗ X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use the shorter notation $\mathbb{P}(I) \equiv |I\rangle\!\rangle\!\langle\!\langle I|$ and $\mathbb{P}(X) \equiv |X\rangle\!\rangle\!\langle\!\langle X|$ for conciseness.

You have
$$
(\mathbb{P}(I)+\mathbb{P}(X))^{\otimes 2}=
\mathbb{P}(I)\otimes\mathbb{P}(I)
+ \mathbb{P}(I)\otimes\mathbb{P}(X)
+ \mathbb{P}(X)\otimes\mathbb{P}(I)
+ \mathbb{P}(X)\otimes\mathbb{P}(X),
$$
where the operators are by definition such that $\mathbb{P}(X)(Y)=X \langle X,Y\rangle$ for any $Y$. It follows that
$$(\mathbb{P}(I)+\mathbb{P}(X))^{\otimes 2} (Y\otimes Z)
= (I\otimes I)\langle I,Y\rangle \langle I,Z\rangle
+ (I\otimes X)\langle I,Y\rangle \langle X,Z\rangle
+ (X\otimes I) \langle X,Y\rangle \langle I,Z\rangle
+ (X\otimes X)\langle X,Y\rangle \langle X,Z\rangle.$$
Using $Y=Z=I$ you get your relation.

Comment: Can you expand $\mathbb{P}(X)(Y)=X⟨X,Y⟩$?, I didn't get it.

Comment: that's almost the definition of things like $|X\rangle\!\rangle\!\langle\!\langle X|$. Though technically it should be $\mathbb{P}(X)(Y)=|X\rangle\!\rangle \langle X,Y\rangle$, with the vectorised operator as output, not the operator itself. This is analogous to what a "ketbra" like $|\psi\rangle\!\langle \psi|$ mean: an operator which given any vector $|\phi\rangle$ returns $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi,\phi\rangle$

Comment: But how comes the trace term, $\langle X,Y\rangle=tr(XY^{\dagger})$, it can't produce the $X\otimes Y$ in trace term $tr(X\otimes Y)$

Comment: @Karry $\langle X,Y\rangle=tr(XY^{\dagger})$ is just the definition of inner product in this case, see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator

Comment: thank you, but it seems that I can't get $tr(X\otimes I)$ from your equation $(\mathbb{P}(I)+\mathbb{P}(X))^{\otimes 2} (Y\otimes Z)
= (I\otimes I)\langle I,Y\rangle \langle I,Z\rangle
+ (I\otimes X)\langle I,Y\rangle \langle X,Z\rangle
+ (X\otimes I) \langle X,Y\rangle \langle I,Z\rangle
+ (X\otimes X)\langle X,Y\rangle \langle X,Z\rangle$. using $Y=Z=I$

Comment: @Karry if $Y=Z=I$ then $\langle X,Y\rangle \langle I,Z\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(X)\operatorname{tr}(I)=\operatorname{tr}(X\otimes I)$

Comment: Oh, I see, Thanks.  : )